# Rails: Active Model explanation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the difference from Active Resource and Active Record in Rails?

Comment: Unless somebody can translate this, it's likely to be closed soon...

Comment: Translation: What the heck is Active Model in Rails for? What's the difference from Active Resource and Active Record?

Comment: This is stuff you can read about in Rails documentation. ActiveResource has absolutely no relation to the other two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ActiveRecord:** ORM to manage data in a relational database through SQL. [read more..](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/README.rdoc)

**ActiveResource:** Manage data through a REST API on another server, no longer a part of Rails, but extracted as a gem. [read more..](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/master/README.rdoc)

**ActiveModel:** Behavior (mixins) to make any Ruby object act like it's ActiveRecord or ActiveResource by adding validations, callbacks, naming conventions, tracking, etc. [read more..](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/README.rdoc)

Comment: The second link 404s. Can anyone fix?

Comment: @finiteloop It's not there anymore, because ActiveResource has been removed from Rails 4. The old documentation is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activeresource/README.rdoc

Comment: Ohh. Good to know. So using ActiveResource in a new rails app would not be a wise decision then, correct?

Comment: Actually, ActiveResource has been resurrected in its gem form and is being actively maintained. See http://yetimedia.tumblr.com/post/35233051627/activeresource-is-dead-long-live-activeresource

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord acts as a layer between a specific database and your application. It is a conventional Object Relationship Mapper (ORM).

ActiveResource acts as a layer between a more abstract network resource such as a REST server and your application. It acts as a sort of wrapper to make a REST resource appear as a database model so similar techniques can be used.